# how to import data from api what writes in typescript to vue js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a typescript file where is written such code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import store from "./store";
import {fullUrl} from "@/helpers";

interface ServerSentEvent extends Event {
    data?: any
}

interface ServerSentEventSource extends EventSource {
    addEventListener: (type: string, listener: (e: ServerSentEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions) => void
}

axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

axios.interceptors.response.use(r => r, e => {
    const {response} = e;
    if (response.status === 422) {
        store.commit('showValidationErrors', response.data.errors)
    }
    if (response.status === 401) {
        window.location.reload()
    }
    throw e;
});

export const http = axios;

export const users = {
    list: () => http.get('users').then(r => r.data),
    activate: id => http.post(`users/status/${id}`),
    view: id => http.get(`users/view/${id}`).then(r => r.data),
    attending: () => http.get(`users/attending`).then(r => r.data),
    emailsend: id => http.get(`users/emailsend/${id}`).then(r => r.data),
```

how to import data from it, I would say attending and emailsend?

I tried to write such line of code  attending = users.attending in my vue js project, but get something like this one '() => http.get(`users/attending`).then(r => r.data)'.

Comment: You're assigning the function instead of invoking it which is done with parentheses: `users.attending()`

Comment: yeah I did it but I have the error "Error: Request failed with status code 404", what does it mean?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404  probably the URL is incorrect or server is not running

Comment: Thank you, I did as you tell me and everything is work fine